# How kotlin decides parameter name in lambda?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm new to kotlin and I'm trying to develop a gradle plugin.
The parameter name confuses me when I implement a Java function interface called `org.gradle.api.Action`.

My code.

```
val action: Action<AppliedPlugin> = Action { // Tip from IDEA "this:AppliedPlugin"
    
}
```

The function interface in Java.

```
public interface Action<T> {
    /**
     * Performs this action against the given object.
     *
     * @param t The object to perform the action on.
     */
    void execute(T t);
}
```

I'm confused by the tip, because I think parameter's default name is `it` not `this`.

Then I declared another Java function interface and implemented it. This time tip is `it:AppliedPlugin!`. Here is my code and temp function interface.

```
val temp: Temp<AppliedPlugin> = Temp { // Tip from IDEA "it:AppliedPlugin!"

}
```

```
public interface Temp<T> {

    void test(T t);
}
```

Can someone explain why kotlin use `this` as the default parameter name in the first lambda?

Comment: I'm confused with the notation. This doesn't seem valid kotlin to me.  Are you trying to assign an anonymous object? Because then you need `object :` in front of it. Also this wouldn't be a lambda then

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yeah it's an anonymous object. I found the notation in here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions

Comment: ah okay, but you need `fun interface` then, not `public interface`

Comment: @IvoBeckers But the gradle api is Java interface and there is a conversion in kotlin. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions.

Comment: Ah now I understand, I didn't realize the interface was java code

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes. I am going to edit my question description and make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that `org.gradle.api.Action<T>` is marked with [`@HasImplicitReceiver`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/HasImplicitReceiver.html), according to its [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html). The effect of `HasImplicitReceiver` is exactly that you can refer to the lambda parameter using `this` (which can be omitted most of the time):

> Marks a SAM interface as a target for lambda expressions / closures where the single parameter is passed as the implicit receiver of the invocation (`this` in Kotlin, `delegate` in Groovy) as if the lambda expression was an extension method of the parameter type.

It's *sort of* like writing this in Kotlin, in the sense that `this` is the lambda parameter.

```
fun interface Action<T> {
    fun T.execute()
}
```

But the above is not exactly the same because you can only call `execute` in very few places, unlike the Java version.

This is useful in writing gradle plugins because having to type `it.` everywhere in your build.gradle isn't very nice.

Note that this is something specific to the Gradle APIs. In Kotlin in general, you wouldn't be able to do something like this. If you have a SAM interface like this:

```
public interface Action<T> {
    void execute(T t);
}
```

the lambda parameter is always `it`, or some other name that you give.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps me a lot.  I totally ignored the annotation.